# How to get all the items present in a folder in google drive and also their respective download links in dart or flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api, drive

Get all those folder names in the form of list as the output after fetching from the link.
The link is of a google drive folder which contains some pdf files and the task is to fetch all the pdf file names and return in the form of list.

Also the download link of each pdf file should be returned.

All of these should be worked with flutter/dart

**If any other details needed please comment below**

Comment: if this is the share with me Link your not going to have google drive api access with that.   To use the drive API you need permission on the file

Comment: It is an open to all google drive url